# Apostroph für Auslassung von -e

Tags: punctuation

Ich habe gestern in meinem Lieblingsbuch (hust hust) "Der Dativ ist des Genitiven Tod" (Band 2) gelesen, dass man beim Imperativ schreibt:

> Schreib!

und nicht

> Schreib'!

Die Begründung war, dass ein ausgelassenes -e am Wortende den Regeln zufolge nie mittels Apostroph angedeutet wird.

- Gibt es diese Regel wirklich?
- Soll allen Ernstes das Folgende richtig sein?

> Ich hab dich angerufen.

und das hier falsch

> Ich hab' dich angerufen.

Comment: Wenn Du den Imperativ „schreib“ mit einem Apostroph verzieren möchtest, möchtest Du dann so auch bei fehlendem Dativ-e verfahren?

Comment: @Carsten Schultz: um den Imperativ geht es mir garnicht so sehr wie um den normalen Aussagesatz. Wenn man das jetzt schon schreiben darf (muss) ohne es kenntlich zu machen, dann müssen doch wohl bald mal alle Konjugationsregeln überarbeitet werden. Und was meinst du mit Dativ-e... hab' ich irgendwo einen Fehler?

Comment: Ok, Du siehst den gleichen Unterschied wie ich, nämlich dass der Infinitv „schreib“ eine mögliche Variante ist, während bei „ich hab“ tatsächlich etwas fehlt. Ansonsten hätte ich halt vorschlagen wollen, dass Du auch „[Früchte, die von einem Baum' oder einem Strauch' auf ein Nachbargrundstück hinüberfallen, gelten als Früchte dieses Grundstücks](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dativ#Dativ-e)“ schreibst, falls Du an den entsprechenden Stellen keine e's benutzt. Das mag polemisch sein, war aber durch Deine Bezeichnung „Schwachsinn“ hervorgerufen, die ich für unangemessen halte.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: du hast wohl Recht... Ich kann Sick einfach nicht leiden. Hab''''s entfernt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Die Regeln des [Rats für deutsche Rechtschreibung](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/regelwerk.html) lassen hier wenig Spielraum für eigene Vorlieben:

> **§96** Man setzt den Apostroph in drei Gruppen von Fällen.
>   (2) Wörter mit Auslassungen, die ohne Kennzeichnung schwer lesbar
>   oder missverständlich sind: *In wen’gen Augenblicken … ’s ist schade um ihn. Das Wasser rauscht’, das Wasser schwoll.*
>
> **§97** Man kann den Apostroph setzen, wenn Wörter gesprochener Sprache
>   mit Auslassungen bei schriftlicher Wiedergabe undurchsichtig sind.
>   *der Käpt’n, mit’m Fahrrad*

In allen anderen Fällen, also wenn das Wort auch mit der Auslassung gebräuchlich und gut 
verständlich ist, wird **kein** Apostroph gesetzt.

Richtig sind also:

> Ich hab dich angerufen.
>   Schreib!

Siehe hierzu auch [Duden mit weiteren Beispielen](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/apostroph#K16).

Comment: Und so brach ich endgültig mit der Reform und schrieb fortan wie mir beliebte... mal im Ernst... das ist einfach nur purer Schwachsinn

Comment: @Emanuel, war es vor der Reform anders? Und natürlich kannst Du in Deinen Texten schreiben wie es Dir beliebt.

Comment: @Carsten Schultz: stimmt. Das weiß ich nicht. Aber ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass es früher in der Tat anders war.

Comment: @Emanuel: Mir fällt's auch schwer, da ich's anders lernen mußte ;)

Comment: Der Imperativ *schreib* (ohne Apostroph) ist übrigens auch gemäß meines Dudens von 1926 orthografisch korrekt – also nichts mit Rechtschreibreform. Außerdem finde ich, dass § 97 recht offen gehalten ist und eine ganze Menge Spielraum lässt.

Answer (score 3):

Ich weiß schon, dass diese Frage sehr alt ist, aber ich bin durch Deinen Blog hergekommen, und wollte mal hier etwas beitragen. Es geht darum, dass die Form ohne "*-e*" tatsächlich die Richtige ist, und *nicht* eine Abkürzung von der *mit* dem "*-e*", sondern die Form damit ist eher eine Erweiterung der Grundform, und zwar die Form ohne ein "*-e*" dahinter.

Diese erweiteten Formen kamen daher, dass man eine Vergleichung zu den Verben gemacht hat, die ursprünglich das "*-e*" im Imperativ gebraucht hatten, denn sie waren von einer Klasse der schwachen Verben, die immer ein *e* oder ein *i* am Ende des Worts hatten, wenn sie schon endungslos waren.

Mehr dazu hier: http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/imperativ.php

Hab eigentlich Belles Lettres auf Deinem Blog gefunden. Hast Du diese Folge da schon gesehen?

Comment: Willkommen! Eine kleine allgemeine Anmerkung: Wie fast an den meisten Stellen des Internets duzen wir uns hier. Und dies ist Deine Website ebenso wie meine, Du musst also nicht von „Ihrer/Eurer Website“ reden. Ich nehme an, dass Du “web site” meintest und nicht “web page”, als du „Webseite“ schriebst. Damit bist Du in der Gesellschaft vieler Deutscher, es ist aber trotzdem ungenau.

Comment: Vielen Dank :). Normalerweise duze ich jeden im Internet, aber irgendwie hats mir geschienen, als würde hier sich alle siezen. Ich bin mir nicht sicher warum. Aber trotzdem danke ich Dir. :)

Komischerweise hab ich auch Emanuel auf seiner Website (;)) geduzt, und ich wollte ihn auch hier aus dem Bauch heraus duzen. Vielleicht hätt ich dabei geblieben sollen. :)

Und das mit der "*Webseite*", na ja, ich dachte als Fremdsprachler, dass das immer ein Anglizismus war und ursprünglich hätt ich auch "Website" gesagt, aber ich sah "Webseite" so oft gelesen, dass ich meine Meinung geändert hatte.

Comment: Richtig, es wäre schön, wenn sich ein einfaches deutsches Wort für [Website](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website) durchgesetzt hätte, aber [im Gegensatz zum Schwedischen](http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webbplats) hat es das nicht.