# Why is the verb not in the second position?

Tags: word-order

Why is the verb not in the second position? Are the following two sentences both imperative sentences? Is that the reason the verb is not in the second position? And what's "versuch's"? Shouldn't it be "versuchst"?

> Konzentrier dich auf einen festen Punkt. Und versuch's wieder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exactly, both are imperative sentences, and that's the reason why the verb is in first position.

"Versuch's" is short for "versuch es", where "versuch" is the imperative form of *versuchen*.

So it's the same as

> Und versuch es wieder. *(And try [it] again)*

In German, other than in English, you need the object for *versuchen*, it doesn't work without "es" here.

Comment: I would have used “versuche”, but it’s a choice.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that *konzentrieren* is a reflexive verb here, thus the *dich* in the first sentence.

Comment: @CarstenS: in fact, it is not a choice and your version ("versuche") is correct. "versuch" is just an abbreviation for "versuche" - a such widely used one, in fact, that the correct form "versuch'" (with an apostrophe at the end) is uncommon. The same, btw., for "konzentrier" -> "konzentrier'/konzentriere".

Comment: @bakunin: source? Duden says otherwise: https://www.duden.de/konjugation/versuchen

Comment: @HalvarF: first, as has often been stated, the Duden is not the definitive authority, when it comes to the german language. Second, even the Duden says "versuche" in "Versuche dich" as an alternative. Third: German has the tendency to remove "-e" endings generally. The same effect can be seen with the "Dativ-e". In fact, even if an "-e" is indeed pronounced it is most of the times pronounced not as "e" but as "schwa". "Schwa", now, is a already a zero grade ("Schwundstufe") of an "e" sound.

Comment: @bakunin you don't need to believe in Duden, but you stated "it is not a choice and your version ("versuche") is correct". That is quite a bold statement, and if it's true, I would edit the answer, that's why I asked what you base it on. I don't see anything supporting this statement in your comment.

Comment: @HalvarF: i could have probably found a somewhat better wording. The basic takeaway is: German has a general tendency to remove endings in "-e". This effect can be seen in the slow removal of the Dativ-e as well as the "-e" in imperative forms. The original ending was "-e" (like "versuche", konzentriere", etc.) in 2nd person singular active present time imperative, but removing it is already so common that the "removal-apostrophe" is not even written any more - at least in most cases: "Werd' (endlich) ..." seems to need an apostrophe still.

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/8220/35111